# Uploading application content to Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am attempting to make my first Android application using the Firebase free trial for the server side of things. My app is fairly limited in scope and it is basically just a way of viewing some pre-created content that I have made.

I have manually created some JSON for the app to parse, and along with the JSON I have some images which I want the app to be able to download. However, I have no idea of how to store these images in Firebase so that they can be retrieved by the app.

My issue is... I have searched every variation of "Upload images to firebase" which I can think of and they are all about the user uploading their own content to Firebase via the app and not for me to upload the content of the app so it is available to be downloaded by the user.

Would anyone be able to point me in the direction of how to set this up? I can upload my JSON to Firebase to create the "database", it is just I do not know how to go about uploading my application data to Firebase so that users can then view it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload your images manually from **Firebase Storage.** 
from the left menu choose Storage and then upload file.

[image]

If you need the image URL. Press on the image and it will show details section at the bottom of this section you will find **Download URL**